# I need to get the last inserted msg for distinct user ID from the mysql table

Tags: codeigniter

My table structure is as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trans_query_discussion` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `query_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_txt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->db->from(tablename);
 $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
 $this->db->limit(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**

> I Hope you need `sender_id` to be equel

---

**Method 01** - (***I personally recommend this***)

```
public function FunctionName($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM trans_query_discussion WHERE sender_id = '$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    print_r($result);
}
```

**Method 02**

```
public function FunctionName($id)
{
    $limit = 1;
    $offset = 0;
    $this->db->get_where('trans_query_discussion', array('sender_id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->limit(1);
    $reslut = $query->result_array();
    print_r($reslut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! for you support, I found the solution through some more head banging :)
in the query like ::

Select * from trans_query_discussion WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id)FROM trans_query_discussion WHERE sender_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(sender_id) FROM trans_query_discussion where sender_id!=52) GROUP BY sender_id) ORDER BY created_time DESC